# Java LDAP Error while doing the lookup

Tags: java, ldap-query

I am doing a lookup of the Object in the Sun One LDAP and getting the exception given below:

**javax.naming.NamingException: problem generating object using object factory [Root

  exception is java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class javax.naming.spi.NamingManager can

  not access a member of class com.ldap.java.LDAPFactory with modifiers "public"]; remaining 
  name cn=favorite,dc=xxx,dc=abc,dc=cdf'**

The exception is thrown in the code given below where "Read Object back":

```
        Fruit fruit = new Fruit("orange", "sweet and sour");

        // Perform bind
        ctx.bind("cn=favorite,dc=xxx,dc=abc,dc=cdf", fruit);
        logger.info("Entry bind...Complete");

        // Read object back
        Object f2 = ctx.lookup("cn=favorite,dc=xxx,dc=abc,dc=cdf");
        logger.info("Fruit = " + f2);

        // Read attributes to see encoding
        Attributes attrs = 
                    ctx.getAttributes("cn=favorite,dc=xxx,dc=abc,dc=cdf");
        logger.info("Atrributes = " + attrs);

        // Close the context when we're done
        ctx.close()
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong in the code?

--

Tks
Bharat

Comment: It seems some jars missing in classpath.

Comment: I don't think that any jar is missing. if the jar was missing, then exception should be like classnotfoundexception.

Comment: It is trying reflection, as per java doc  it could be due to classdef not found http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalAccessException.html

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem by the following piece of code:

Existing Code:

```
    String classname = Fruit.class.getName();
    StringRefAddr classref = new StringRefAddr("java:".concat(name), fruit + ":" + fruitType);
    String classfactoryname = FruitFactory.class.getName();

    Reference ref = new Reference(classname, classref, classfactoryname, null);

    logger.info("getReference(): END");

    return ref;
```

New Code:

```
    String classname = Fruit.class.getName();
    StringRefAddr classref = new StringRefAddr("java:".concat(name), fruit + ":" + fruitType);
    //String classfactoryname = FruitFactory.class.getName();

    Reference ref = new Reference(classname, classref);

    return ref;
```

-- 
Tks 
Bharat